# В чём разница между putExtra и putSerializable?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, сериализация

И тот и другой метод передаёт информацию через intent, тогда почему в одном случае используется  putExtra, а в другом putSerializable?

Comment: Расширьте вопрос, добавьте код. Насколько я помню, у `Intent` есть `putExtra`, а у `Bundle` есть `putSerializable`, но не наоборот

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov, благодарю!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если танцевать от печки, то первичным является концепция `Parcel` - по сути это специальный способ сериализации (если точнее механизм IPC) применяемый в Android. На техническом уровне, нужно имплементировать интерфейс `Parcelable`. Документация говорит:

> Parcel is not a general-purpose serialization mechanism. This class (and the corresponding Parcelable API for placing arbitrary objects into a Parcel) is designed as a high-performance IPC transport.

Однако, в плане кода реализация `Parcel/Parcelable` достаточно затратна, поэтому предусмотрены упрощенные способы:

1. `putExtra(String, String/long/int)` и.т.д
2. `putExtra(String, Bundle)` - где `Bundle` - пакет, который может содержать в.т.ч `Serializable/String/int/long/Parcelable` и проч.

При этом важно понимать, что под капотом все равно лежит `Parcel/Parcelable`

Например `putExtra(String, boolean)` под капотом (в исходниках) выглядит так:

```
public Intent putExtra(String name, boolean value) {
    if (mExtras == null) {
        mExtras = new Bundle();
    }
    mExtras.putBoolean(name, value);
    return this;
}
```

То есть по сути все значения все равно упаковываются в `Bundle`, а если начать раскручивать `Bundle`, то там выглядывают рожки от `Parcelable`

Comment: Отличное объяснение, спасибо. Единственно, я всё ещё не понял, в каких случаях используется один метод, а в каких другой?

Comment: `putSerializable` надо использовать если у вас есть Java объект, который реализует интерфейс `Serializable`, а `putExtra` когда используются простые типы

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Между активностями и фрагментами вы можете коммуницировать при помощи [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/Intent) и [Bundle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle). Как вам уже было сказано в комментариях у `intent` нет метода [putSerializable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle#putSerializable(java.lang.String,%20java.io.Serializable)). Данный метод есть у `bundle`. Но если вам нужно передать какой-то `serializable` объект то вы можете воспользоваться методом `putExtra()` и в него уже положить свои данные. Есть так же и другой способ передачи `serializable` в `intent` - формируете `bundle` и его кладете в `intent` при помощи `putExtra()`

Comment: премного благодарен!